# Changing Pushpin Text Color

Tags: android, bing-maps, pushpin

I'm attempting to display data through the text of a `Pushpin` object. However, the text color defaults to white which is nigh-invisible when the backdrop is a road-style `MapView`. Looking through the API, paying especially close attention to `PushpinOptions`, I couldn't find anything that manipulated text color. Considering that this seems to a fairly basic feature, I'm a little confused as to why it doesn't exist or at least is really hard to find.

Am I missing something or does Bing Maps for Android really not let you change the default text color for a `Pushpin` object?

Comment: I looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798874/how-to-format-the-text-or-change-the-font-size-inside-pushpin-in-bingmaps-ajax But it doesn't help as it doesn't apply to Bing Maps for Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having had a look through the source there is no support for changing the text color as it stands.

The source is available at http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/ so you may be able to hack it to get what you are after depending if the Bing Maps API itself supports what you are after.  This will of course require a bit of extra effort but may be your only option other than a workaround using layers.

**UPDATE**

Having done a little extra digging about in the [MSDN documentation for the pushpin class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427615) it doesn't appear to be supported not sure if there is a more ingenious way around this with CSS but it's not going to be a simple matter of implementing additional features of the API

Comment: there's a map.html file in the assets folder of the [source code](http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/) ... you might want to start there